# Marking std::unique_ptr class member as const

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, ownership

A lot of the examples for using `std::unique_ptr` to manage ownership of class dependencies look like the following:

```
class Parent
{
public:
    Parent(Child&& child) :
    _child(std::make_unique<Child>(std::move(child))){}
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Child> _child;
};
```

My question is whether marking the `_child` member as `const` have any unexpected side effects? (Aside from being ensuring that `reset()`, `release()` etc. cannot be called on `_child`).

I ask since I have not yet seen it in an example and don't whether that is intentional or just for brevity/generality.

Comment: Ask yourself: If it is `const` can it be moved from?

Comment: Are you saying there are lots of examples that fail to compile? The one you show certainly does. In particular, `_child(std::move(child))` part makes no sense.

Comment: Trying to move a  `const` unique_ptr will fail to compile as copying is deleted and there is no constructor that takes a const rvalue ref.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that's not what I was implying at all - both versions compile fine :)

Comment: @GillBates - ah yes, good point! I felt like I was missing something, but couldn't quite place it :) Feel free to add it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct

Comment: @RichardHodges the question originally had a typo in - it's now been edited out.

Comment: @PeetWhittaker I see. I'm always late to the party... Will remove the comment.

Comment: @richardhodges Ctrl + F5 at least 10 times a minute.

Comment: Ask yourself: what would Jesus do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because of the nature of a `std::unique_ptr`(sole ownership of an object) it's required to have no copy constructor whatsoever. The [move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr)(6) only takes non-const rvalue-references which means that if you'd try to make your `_child` `const` and move it you'd get a nice compilation error :)

Even if a custom `unique_ptr` would take a const rvalue-reference it would be impossible to implement.

Comment: @nwp Why sholdn't it? It doesn't attempt to copy or move an instance of `Parent`.

Comment: @nwp because it constructs a `unique_ptr` through the moved *non* const `child`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Nothing in the question states that `Parent` must be movable, and it could be made to.

Comment: The question asked about `_child` being `const`, the member variable, not `child` the parameter.

Comment: I see in the original question that I made a small error, the `Parent` constructor should have taken `std::unique_ptr<Child>&&` as its param, not `Child&&`. I'm not sure that would affect things though?

Comment: Not much, as @nwp said the current implementation allows moving into the const unique_ptr but this prevents any copy or move operation for Parent as the const unique ptr is disallowing it.

Comment: @nwp The OP asked what the "unexpected side effects" might be of making `_child` member const. Rendering `Parent` non-movable is a side effect that the OP didn't appear to expect.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I agree, and that is what I wrote in my answer. This answer, however, is talking about a compilation error and I'm not sure where/why that would be.

Comment: @nwp "if you'd try to make your `_child` const and move it you'd get a nice compilation error" note the _and move it_ (through moving `Parent`).

Answer (score 1):

The downsides are like with any `const` member: That the assignment and move-assignment operators don't work right (they would require you to overwrite `_child`) and that moving from the parent would not steal the `_child` (performance bug). Also it is uncommon to write code like this, possibly confusing people.

The gain is marginal because `_child` is `private` and therefore can only be accessed from inside the `Parent`, so the amount of code that can break invariants revolving around changing `_child` is limited to member functions and friends which need to be able to maintain invariants anyways.

I cannot imagine a situation where the gain would outweigh the downsides, but if you do you can certainly do it your way without breakage of other parts of the program.

Comment: Good points. Probably explains why I haven't seen it before in any examples!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this, and it's what I regularly do when implementing UI classes in Qt:

```
namespace Ui {
    class MyWidget
}

class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT  

    const std::unique_ptr<Ui::MyWidget> ui;

public:
    explicit MyWidgetQWidget *parent = 0)
        : ui(new Ui::MyWidget{})
    {
    }

    ~MyWidgetQWidget();
    // destructor defined as = default in implementation file,
    // where Ui::MyWidget is complete
}
```

It's exactly comparable to writing `Ui::MyWidget *const ui` in C++03 code.

The above code creates a new object, but there's no reason not to pass one in using `std::move()` as in the question.